# Is it possible to check if memory allocated during call was less than X

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, .net-7.0

So I have an interface function that is a black box for me and I need to test. It is acting in managed code only. I have algorithm restrictions on memory size. I want to control that during the call `<= X` amount of ram was consumed in peak during the call. In other words I want to limit or control total allocateble space in a given scope and if we get over that limit throw. How to do such thing in .Net?

So I want something like

```
wrapper.setMemLimit = 1000; // in bytes
try { 
 wrapper.run(methodToTest());
} catch (Exception e) {
 // hit mem cap limit during execution!
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll find a good way to do this with C#/.NET. There have been many proposals, but no such tight control over memory was implemented. The best you can do is run the computation in a separate process or launch an extra .NET runtime - of course, still rather unreliable since there are many other costs involved. Why do you need to do this? Grading student assignments? How reliable and precise does it have to be? What kind of overhead do you tolerate?

Answer (score 1):

.NET is a managed environment (i.e. memory is managed by it) and in addition there is threading - it is quite hard to get this information reliably.

You can try using [`GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.gettotalallocatedbytes?view=net-5.0) for some ballpark estimations in some cases (get value before and after the method and calculate diff):

> Gets a count of the bytes allocated over the lifetime of the process. The returned value does not include any native allocations.

But this will do the trick only for single-threaded processing (or if the only thing application runs is the algorithm) and as quoted will not cover the native/unmanaged allocations. Also it will not account the any GC happening during the method (so actual memory allocation can be less then the calculated value).

Or [`GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.getallocatedbytesforcurrentthread?view=net-5.0) (if the algorithm is single-threaded):

> Gets the total number of bytes allocated to the current thread since the beginning of its lifetime.

Or [`GC.GetTotalMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.gettotalmemory?view=net-5.0):

> Retrieves the number of bytes currently thought to be allocated. A parameter indicates whether this method can wait a short interval before returning, to allow the system to collect garbage and finalize objects.

Another approach is to look into profiling your application ([with VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2022), [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or with [`dotnet monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-monitor), and other tools like [`dotnet gcdump`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-gcdump)). Again - monitoring actual consumed memory in managed environments is not an easy task (especially tied to some method) so these tools were developed. Some automation can be achieved with [ClrMD](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd) also.

Comment: @Luaan yep, mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: The GC can mean the actual memory allocation can be both less and _more_ than reported (depending on what actually got collected). If the code being tested is simple and small enough, and you only do this as part of some testing mechanism (rather than running the code as part of some actual application), you could get somewhat useful data by forcing a GC and WaitForFinalizers before running the code, and of course running the code multiple times etc. But that might not be viable for the OP, and is still tricky (e.g. stack allocations are not on the GC heap).

Comment: @Luaan yep, that is why _"for some ballpark estimations"_ is there =)